# how to display value in an anonymous window?

Tags: apex

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Exchange_rate__c> getDate(String selectStartDay, String selectFinalDay ){
    List<Exchange_rate__c> exchangeDate = [SELECT Date__c FROM Exchange_rate__c WHERE Date__c =: selectStartDay AND Date__c =: selectFinalDay];
    system.debug('======'+ exchangeDate);
    return exchangeDate;
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: What would you exactly want to do? If you want to execute this in Anonymous window, you need to call the `<class_name>.getDate(...)` and see the result in logs.

Comment: I want to see what my request shows        system.debug('======'+ exchangeDate);

Comment: I do not understand how to write code in an anonymous window, because it requests values

Comment: You need to pass the parameters if you are running this snippet in anonymous window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want actual value when the code is running check the actual **debug logs** for that transaction and look for your debug statement.

If you are aware of the selectStartDay and selectFinalDay you can run this in your **anonymous window** to get the debug printed.

```
String selectStartDay = 'your value here';
String selectFinalDay = 'your value here';
List<Exchange_rate__c> exchangeDate = [SELECT Date__c FROM Exchange_rate__c WHERE Date__c =: selectStartDay AND Date__c =: selectFinalDay];
system.debug('======'+ exchangeDate);
```

Comment: thanks Nishant worked